# Facebook Comment Social Plugin + Wall Post to Facebook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-comments

I have created Facebook application and using application id i have used Facebook comment social plugin on my asp.net mvc website

Now problem is when i comment using comment plugin with checkbox post to wall checked,
i want to display my application logo with that comment on my wall.

So, i will greatly appreciate if you will help me on above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please put open graph metatag in header section.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="logo path" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot naresh pansuriya.. its working now........ you save lot of time.....